# Convert Excel to JSON

Tags: c#, json, excel, asp.net-core, file-upload

I can not convert xlsx to JSON.

I tried thus:

```
var jsonString = string.Empty;
jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataList, Formatting.Indented);

      public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                string folderName = "Upload";
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                }
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }



                    var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fullPath);

                    //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.

                    var workSheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

                    var firstRowUsed = workSheet.FirstRowUsed();

                    var firstPossibleAddress = workSheet.Row(firstRowUsed.RowNumber()).FirstCell().Address;

                    var lastPossibleAddress = workSheet.LastCellUsed().Address;


                    // Get a range with the remainder of the worksheet data (the range used)

                    var range = workSheet.Range(firstPossibleAddress, lastPossibleAddress).AsRange(); //.RangeUsed();

                    // Treat the range as a table (to be able to use the column names)

                    var table = range.AsTable();


                    //Specify what are all the Columns you need to get from Excel

                    var dataList = new List<string[]>

                    {

                      table.DataRange.Rows()


                        .Select(tableRow =>
                          tableRow.Field("Condition").GetString())
                        .ToArray(),

                      table.DataRange.Rows()

                        .Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("rules__field").GetString())

                        .ToArray(),
                       table.DataRange.Rows()

                        .Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("rules__operator").GetString())

                        .ToArray(),
                        table.DataRange.Rows()

                        .Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("rules__value").GetString())

                        .ToArray(),

                    };


                    var jsonString = string.Empty;
                    jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataList, Formatting.Indented);


                }

                return Json("Upload Successful.");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

**Output Received:**

```
[
  [
      "and"
  ],
  [
      "Id"
  ],
  [
      "Contains"
  ],
  [
      "4000030000502"
  ]
]
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
    "condition": "and",
    "rules": [
        { 
          "field": "Id", 
          "operator": "Contains", 
          "value": "4000030000502"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does the xlsx worksheet look like?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it sort of does not matter... The question is roughly "please run Json2CSharp converter for me to create classed and than I can populate data from XLSX"... Really not clear why OP expected JSON to magically figure out why array of arrays should be represented as object...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You're probably correct. Nice re-interpretation of his question. My thought was perhaps there was information in the workbook that would allow that to occur.

Comment: It looks like you've tried a few things and gotten part of the way there. The question is how far. For example, does your `DataTable` have what you expect it to? If so, that's good news. Then the question is no longer how to convert from Excel to JSON, but to format the contents of your `DataTable` as JSON. If the contents of your `DataTable` are not what you expect then the problem is further back. ...and, what does your xlsx look like?